# Remove MVC 5 EditorTemplate additional ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I am using this Editor Template for Dropdownlist with ViewBag/ViewData of same property Name

```
@model System.String
@*
    For Using this Editor Template
    - There should be a viewbag/viewdata (type SelectList) of same name as of calling Model's Property
*@
@{
    var modelMetadata = ViewData.ModelMetadata;
    // Get property name of the model
    var propertyname = modelMetadata.PropertyName;
}

@if (ViewData[propertyname] == null)
{
    @Html.DropDownList(propertyname , Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownList(propertyname , null, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

now using it as 
`@Html.EditorFor(i=>i.Country,"CustomDropDown")`
I also have a ViewBag.Country as SelectList of countries.

Everything works fine, but now the Naming of the Control becomes

```
<select class="form-control" id="Country_Country" name="Country.Country">
```

how to remove the additional `Country` from the id and name?

**Additional Info:**

I could have just used the `@Html.DropDownList("Country")` but it doesn't allow me to add the css class to the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the Solution.

I changed the DropDownList to DropDownListFor with some changes

```
@if (ViewData[propertyname] == null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, ViewData[propertyname] as SelectList, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

this auto ViewData bind is kind of confusing at times. >_<